# How do I create a shortcode that displays a youtube video from its id in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to write a shortcode that displays a youtube video when the user puts the id in.

For example my shortcode would look like this:

`[youtube id="SP6abPzY300GVnc8pGr8qqd6U0eABNPHf6"]`

In the front end this would then display the youtube video on my blog page.

The code I have so far is:

```
function wp_youtube_video($atts) {
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(

          'id' => ''

     ), $atts));

    return $id;
}
add_shortcode('youtube', 'wp_youtube_video');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will return the YouTube ID if you changed `return $id` to `return $atts['id']`. However, you will need to associate that ID to a YouTube video embed code in order for it to be displayed correctly. Something like this perhaps...

```
    function wp_youtube_video($atts) {
         extract(shortcode_atts(array(

              'id' => ''

         ), $atts));

        return '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html"    width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$atts['id'].'" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>';
    }
    add_shortcode('youtube', 'wp_youtube_video');
```

Comment: Good answer, but instead of `$atts['id']`, `$id` will work because of the earlier `extract()` function call.